# Display Tableau Report using Embedding API V3 on a SPO Page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tableau-api, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have a requirement to display a tableau report on a SharePoint Online Modern page using their embedding API V3 which is provided here - https://help.tableau.com/current/api/embedding_api/en-us/index.html. The issue I'm facing with the below code is on how to load a script as a module in an SPFx webpart. I'm aware I can use SPComponentLoader to load a script using loadScript which gives me an error as it cannot load the script as a module. How to load it as a module so that I can use the below web component to display the report on a SPO modern page?

I'm open to other suggestions on how to display static html but I've ruled out iFrame as I cannot pass query string parameters to the code dynamically using that method.

Is Modern Script Editor built with react a good choice or a no framework spfx webpart will work?

Will this.domElement.innerHTML be able to run the Script tag as a module?

NOTE: There are some npm modules wrapped with tableau embedding api v2 but I'm trying to use v3 because it is the latest and none of the npm modules are officially maintained by tableau.

```
<script type="module" src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau.embedding.3.latest.min.js%22%3E</script>
<tableau-viz id="tableauViz" src='https://public.tableau.com/views/Superstore_embedded_800x800/Overview'
  toolbar="bottom" hide-tabs>
</tableau-viz>
```

I'm stuck on this for a while and any help would be greatly appreciated.